# Microsoft Visual Studio to write C language

Tags: c++, c, visual-studio

Just couple of days ago I saw my friend was using Microsoft Visual studio to write the C language for our assignment and I'm wondering how can he use that.

I use putty connect to our Linux environment but with Microsoft Visual I see that they look more profession and also very useful in a way of managing the codes for us.

I really love to know if is that really works because I didn't have a chance to ask my friend how he gets it work but if anyone of you could please tell me what option would be the same library for C because all I see is C++ and when I tried compile it doesn't seem to work for me

Comment: What c code did you write and test in vs?

Comment: Why not ask about it the next time you see your friend? Note that the Visual C++ compilers can compile C, although their compliance to the C standard is not as good as their compliance to the C++ standard.

Comment: @Ajai I tried with just simple `printf`

Comment: See this link http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb384838.aspx

Comment: @Insilico unfortunately we are now going to be different class (new semester) and not sure if he would even be in the same college :( otherwise I will have asked him next month.

Comment: I suppose you must have not included the proper header files. #include <stdio.h> for instance. Apart from that I find no reason for C code not executing in C++ environment. I have myself ran a couple of C programs in VS and it works just fine if you include all the headers that you used for C

Comment: Omg. Your friend wrote the C language - again? From scratch? I'm impressed.

Comment: @Ajai I have done that but I guess I choose wrong option in the new project?

Comment: @gnometorule we are in Foundation of C language course so we are writing program in C :/

Comment: @Ali Did you choose C++ Console Application? If yes then that should work just fine. There is nothing you need to modify in VS environment..

Comment: @Ajai I'm going to start from scratch again sorry for disturbing your guys

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[You can use the `/TC` compiler option](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/032xwy55%28v=vs.80%29.aspx). Sometimes even with a `.c` extension c files are compiled as C++. 
The link I have posted tells on how to do it from command line as well as IDE